# Can't capture Video from Cam in OpenCV 2.4.7

Tags: c++, opencv

This is my code which I copy/paste from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture):

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error:

---

```
OpenCV error: Assertion failed (scn==3 || scn==4) 
in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737
```

---

I am using Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2008, OpenCV 2.4.7

What can be the problem?

**EDIT:**

It is sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

**EDIT 2:**

I edited **VideoCapture cap(0);** to **cv::VideoCapture cap(0);** then, I rebuild my solution and run it. It worked for the first time, I tried to run for the second time, it gave me the same error.

**EDIT 3:**

I have even edited **for(;;)**:

```
for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("edges", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
```

This time I receive another error:

---

```
OpenCV error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) 
in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
```

---

I guess the problem is with **imshow**.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly does this error occur in your program? As in, does it occur after `cap >> frame` or `cvtColor`..? Please put in breakpoints and get back to me.

Comment: @scap3y I put cout<<"aaaaa"<<endl; after cap>>frame; and cout<<"bbbb"<<endl; after cvtColort, it printed "aaaaa" and then stopped :)

Comment: @scap3y there is another error (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

Comment: The problem is with `cvtColor`, obviously. Might I suggest you change the name of the window and try..? Otherwise, you might need to do a step-by-step debugging and see the value changes in every step.

Comment: @scap3y I solved my problem, I just added cap.read(frame); before cap>>frame, it worked. What do you think about this? Why?

Comment: I am guessing this would be because of the new capture interface; but I am not sure since I tested this out on my system and it worked fine. Weird.

Comment: The documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) suggests that the operator >> is equivalent to VideoCapture::read(). Try once again without the read() function call. The error tells that the frame retrieved from the webcam is of 0 width and height.

Answer (score 2):

I get similar problem. I solve it by putting everything after `cap >> frame` into an if-statement:

```
 for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        if (!frame.empty()) {
          cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
          GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
          Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
          imshow("edges", edges);
        }
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I tested your code in my environment (Win XP 32 bit OS, VS2008, OpenCV2.4.7). It works normally every time. And you can also do it like this:

```
IplImage* frame,*edges;
CvCapture* pcapture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
cvNamedWindow("edges",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (1)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(pcapture);
    if (!frame) break;
    edges = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,1);
    cvCvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvSmooth(edges,edges,CV_GAUSSIAN,7,7,1.5,1.5);
    cvCanny(edges,edges,0,30,3);
    cvShowImage("edges",edges);
    cvReleaseImage(&edges);
    if (cvWaitKey(30)>=0) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture(&pcapture);
cvDestroyWindow("edges");
```

You can have a try whether its also have some problems in your environment or not.
Hope a little help to you!

Comment: oh, pleas *don't* point anyone at the outdated c-api, please even stop using it yourself !